# How to store requests "offline" to perform them later?

Tags: jquery, http, jsf, primefaces

I'm building a web application using jsf and primefaces.

It is a very simple time attendance application, basically employees click a button when they start working and another button when they leave for the day. The timestamps of the click actions are send to the server, where they are processed and stored in a database.

The thing is that when the application is unreachable (network problems, for instance) requests (obviously) cannot be sent to the server. When that happens, I would like to store the time when the user clicked the button (maybe in a javascript variable, or in a cookie) and then automatically send it to the server once the network is back up.

I have done a quick research about it but I haven't found much. Html 5 has a "offline mode", but I cannot rely on that, since I'm working with some legacy browsers (IE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use HTML5 and it's enough for you, you can use `window.localStorage`. It's supported by modern browsers and IE8+. Then you can check this storage when user connects again Internet.

You can make experiments with Firefox/Chrome developer tools.

Getter / Setters

```
window.localStorage.setItem('key','value');
window.localStorage.getItem('key');
```

And you can check if browser does not support *HTML5 web storage*, you can use cookies.